# How to update 10M records in Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, query-optimization

I have two tables - accounts, inf_accounts.
There is a daily update on millions of rows from inf_accounts to accounts.

I tried two updates:

```
UPDATE accounts acc SET account_status=(SELECT account_status FROM inf_accounts inf WHERE acc.account_number = inf.account_number);
```

This one performs kind of OK - 10M rows update in 5-7 mins.
Problem is, it doesn't work as expected. When there are rows in accounts table not to be found in inf_accounts, it obviously crashes.

```
UPDATE accounts acc SET account_status=inf.account_status FROM inf_accounts inf WHERE acc.account_number = inf.account_number;
```

This one works ok but performs horribly - 10M rows update in dozens of minutes.

Is there a way to do it better?

Comment: Start with a query plan, first just `explain` to get a plan (good or bad) and then `explain(analyze, verbose, buffers, settings)` to see what is really going on. The second one does execute the update. The ddl for all tables and indexes involved, would be helpful as well. (all in plain text, as an update to your question)

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier that when `inf_accounts` gets updated to also update `accounts` on the original app workflow so that you don't do the same work twice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your second example statement try appending

```
AND acc.account_status <> inf.account_status
```

to the WHERE clause.  This will make the DBMS refrain from updating rows where the status is already set correctly. If that is most of the rows it will save a ton of time.

Answer (score 1):

One way to approach this is by looking at the data set to be accessed when the `UPDATE` is performed.  You can do this by looking at the results of `SELECT` on the same parameters, and pass through `EXPLAIN`:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT *
FROM accounts acc,
     inf_accounts inf
WHERE acc.account_number = inf.account_number;
```

This will likely reveal whether an index is being used to compare `acc.account_number` and `inf.account_number`.  If not, then you will likely be taking a long time to join the two tables to determine which rows of `accounts` to update.

Additionally, as `O. Jones` mentioned in the other answer, there is no limiting of which rows in `accounts` to update.  Without `AND acc.account_status <> inf.account_status`, you will set `acc.account_status` even if it is already equal to `inf.account_status`, resulting in an unnecessary write, and thereby taking up extra time.

If you haven't already, be sure to index both the `account_status` and `account_number` columns on both tables.  `EXPLAIN` may help you identify the actual bottleneck in the `UPDATE` call (note that `EXPLAIN` will not run the query, but only show the execution plan.  If you want to see the actual runtime performance, use `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` instead)